# How to display multiple notifications in to one notification like gmail is sending notifications dynamically?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I Searched to send continuous notifications but my app is showing so many  notifications in status bar, because that notify Id is random number, so What I want is when notification is there, then if other notification comes then it should not override old notification and it should added as stack like gmail is showing multiple message in one notification,I have seen **Notification with Inbox style**, but How I will implement for dynamic notifications https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html but it is showing static data, I want to implement same thing with dynamic messges, Please let me know if anyone did this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code, try this for notification like the Gmail app.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
    .setContentText("Events received")
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
        new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
String[] events = new String[6];
// Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");
...
// Moves events into the expanded layout
for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}
// Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inBoxStyle);
```

Comment: Here events is static data,I want to display dynamic data, means when I got the notification then If it is 1 then I have to display in BIGStyle not in inbox style if it is more than one notification in stack then I want to display in inbox style.If I want to display dynmic events then I have to store recent notifications data, and add into the inbox style, Is it this way or any other way to display dynamic events